# Is there a theorem deals with $\int_{\Omega} \bigtriangleup u \bigtriangleup v $

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I am working on defining a norm on proving a norm on $H_0^2({\Omega})$, $\Omega $ is bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^N$. But to do that, we need to prove that

$\int_{\Omega} \bigtriangleup u \bigtriangleup v dx =\sum_{i,j=1}^N \int_{\Omega} \partial_{ij}u \;\partial_{ij}v 
 \;dx $.

But, I could not find a formula helps me working on left hand side.

Comment: Try using integration by parts to move the derivatives over. For example if we write $\Delta u = D_i^2 u$ and $\Delta v = D_j^2 u$ (sum over $i,j$). Then $\Delta u\Delta v = D_i[D_iu D_j^2 v] - (D_iu)(D_j^2D_iv)$. Now do the same thing on the last term: pull out the $D_j$ and you will be left with $\Delta u\Delta v = (D_iD_j u)(D_iD_j v) + $ total derivatives which vanish when integrated over the closed surface.

Comment: @Winther. That's makes sense. Thank you!